# PHP - On homepage, display username if logged in, don't display if not logged in

Tags: php, session, authentication, display

how do I display a visitor's username on my homepage(**index.php**) if they're logged in, and how do I not display anything if they're not logged in.

For example, if they're logged in: Welcome, username01!
And if they're not logged in: Welcome! You are not registered yet.

This is my **register.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
//connect to database
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydbname");
if(isset($_POST['register_btn']))
{
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $gender=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password2']);  
    if($password==$password2)
 {      //Create User
        $password=md5($password); //hash password 
        $sql="INSERT INTO users(username,gender,email,password) 
        VALUES('$username','$gender' ,'$email','$password')";
        mysqli_query($db,$sql);  
        $_SESSION['message']="You are now logged in"; 
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        header("location:index.php");  //redirect to home page
}
else
{
  // failed
    $_SESSION['message']="Error. Both passwords do not match.";   
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the username in the session once they're logged on you can do the following:

```
echo isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : '';
```

Checks if the key 'username' is set inside the session, if yes display it other wise leave it blank.

It's better to create a function for it. You might want to display the username somewhere else aswell.

Example:

```
function getUsername() {
    return isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : '';
}
```

Just call `getUsername()` in your code to use it.

Answer (score 0):

**index.php**

```
session_start(); //add this line if you did not start session
echo 'Welcome : '.isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : 'You are not registered yet';
```